# How I can extract specific characters form a string?

Tags: excel, vba, text-extraction

I have following STRING:
1121PDT0011
I want to extract text characters like PDT from STRING and remove digit characters, be aware that the position of PDT in STRING is variable:
45PDT345 or 2PDT and I can not use MID function, how can I do my job in EXCEL VBA?

Comment: Then just remove the digit characters using replace.  Or if you wish a regexp.

Comment: "and I can not use MID function" - why though? It's part of the standard library for a reason? Use it with `InStr`, also in the standard library, also in the `VBA.Strings` module.

Comment: Please update your question to explain exactly what you're doing.  If you extract "PDT" and "remove digit characters" there's nothing left in your imputs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think is the absolute simplest for beginner levels:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "1121PDT0011"
Dim x As Long

For x = 0 To 9
    str = Replace(str, x, "")
Next

Debug.Print str

End Sub
```

Somewhat more advanced could be the use of some regexp object which would actually be more of an text "extraction" instead of replacing what we don't want:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "1121PDT0011"

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]+"
    If .Test(str) Then
        str = .Execute(str)(0)
    End If
End With

Debug.Print str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this UDF.

[image]

```
Function TextOnly(pWorkRng As Range) As String
    Dim xValue      As String
    Dim OutValue    As String
    xValue = pWorkRng.Value
    For xIndex = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
            OutValue = OutValue & VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
        End If
    Next
    TextOnly = OutValue
End Function
```